# Is there any way to write it better?

Tags: python

i have a code like this:

```
page_number = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', total_matches)
page_number = int(page_number) + 1
```

Is there any way to write it better? I mean something like that:

```
x = 5
x += 5
```

Comment: are you incrementing or setting  it equal to?

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner:

```
page_number = int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', total_matches)) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the place where `int` is called.

```
page_number = int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', total_matches))
page_number += 1
```

If it isn't guaranteed that there is always a page number you can catch the exception.

```
try:    
    page_number = int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', total_matches))
except ValueError:
    page_number = 0
page_number += 1
```

Now it's longer but more robust.